# Python HTTP server that execs on POST or evals on GET?

Tags: python, web-services, http, httpserver

I sometimes find I need a function in python that I don't have in my Favourite Programming Language.  I don't want to embed (link) python in my FPL, but I'd like to be able to evaluate and exec Python code over HTTP.

```
example of "1+1":  GET /1%2B1
```

Maybe return any results in JSON.  I'm sure this can be done in a few lines of code.

Comment: The are many REST / microservice frameworks for Python out there.

Comment: @KlausD., it should be easy to do using builtin libraries - eg. socketserver - i spent over an hour on this, but it shouldn't take much.  FPL client sends GET/POST request, python evaluates, sends back result in body.

Comment: Have a look at bottle or flask.

Comment: @KlausD. it's simpler than that